# How to select a record which has a foreign key with more than value?

Tags: sql, select, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a newbie with PlSQL. I have this table which represents relation between 2 tables:

```
ID T1Id T2Id
-- ---- ----
 1    1    1
 2    2    1
 3    2    2
 4    2    3
 5    3    1
...
```

I have values in 2nd column(T1Id) which could have one or more values from 3rd one(T2Id).
My question is how to select only T1Id values which have more than 1 T1Id value.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: As to the table design: it is unusual to give a bridge table an ID of ist own; for this is something you'd normally never need. So I suggest you remove it from the table and make `t1id` + `t2id` the primary key. (If you stick to the ID, then you'd still have to ensure to have all needed unique constraints, i.e. one on `id`, one on `t1id` + `t2id`.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yeap, you are right, I didn't think about it; Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you only want the T1Id values where there is more than one in the table you can use the below.

```
select T1Id, count(T1Id) as countT1 from yourTable
group by T1Id
having count(T1Id) > 1
```

If you wanted to select other columns you can use row partition to achieve this

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*, COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY t1id) AS countT1
          FROM yourTable a)
 WHERE countT1 > 1
```